# Running xsim from cygwin

Tags: cygwin, xilinx, vivado

I get following error , when trying to run xsim commands on cygwin. Please help and let me know What is missing at my end?

```
kap@kap-PC /cygdrive/d
$ echo $XILINX_VIVADO
D:/XilinxV/Vivado/2015.2

kap@kap-PC /cygdrive/d
$ echo $VIVADO
D:\XilinxV\compile_simlib

kap@kap-PC /cygdrive/d
$ xelab
D:/XilinxV/Vivado/2015.2/bin/unwrapped/win64.o/xelab.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: the shared library needed by xelab are not in the PATH. Is xelab a cygwin program ?

Comment: Why are you running a Windows program in Cygwin? At first it's designed to run in Windows natively, at second you need to load the Vivado environment before executing any Xilinx program. At third, such an environment setup is provided as old school Windows batch files instead of PowerShell files. At fourth, Vivado is coming with it's own execution environment, which should be MinGW, so it would be incompatible with Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Our Sim environment is Cgywin based , so we use cygwin to run instead of Vivado's shell.The issue was with setting XILINX_VIVADO as Environment variable. I was setting this thru export in cygwin, but somehow it was not taking. But thru Environment Variable , it works now.